# Single sign on on GlassFish for application on different domains

Tags: java, glassfish

I am running two different applications on different domains of GlassFish3.0.1.

```
I want to implement single sign on for both the application. so when user X has logged in into the domain1's application , that user dont have to relogin for application running on domain2.
```

How can I Implement this single sign on functionality ???

Thank You,
Gunjan Shah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to implement single sign on. One way is to use SAML2 based single sign on. In that case both of you apps on GlassFish need to act as SAML2 service providers and need to have a separate SAML2 IdP. There are many open source SAML2 IdPs - OpenAM, WSO2 Identity Server are few to name..

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com), a hosted SSO platform which also includes fraud protection and two factor authentication.

Disclaimer: I work for Cloudseal :)